# How to install python3 in local drive?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin, drone.io, px4

I am trying to install PX4 firmware on Windows 10 & built it using Cygwin toolchain. However, when I use the `make` command to build the program, it says `python3` not available. I already installed Python 3.8 & it shows in Git bash so why is it not showing in console bash?

Error:-

```
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.14", but required is at least "3" (found /usr/bin/python)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:287 (message):
  Python 3 not found.  Please install Python 3:

      Ubuntu: sudo apt install python3 python3-dev python3-pip
      macOS: brew install python


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/PX4/home/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Error: /cygdrive/c/PX4/home/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default is not a directory
make: *** [Makefile:226: px4_sitl] Error 1
```

Note- the path is correct in the environment variable showing python3.8

Comment: Please do not post images. Please post the text instead.

Comment: alright, didn't know that.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you've installed python 3 in windows and are trying to use python 3 inside cygwin?

Comment: yes, you are right. Don't know how to update python3 in Cygwin.

Comment: Install python3 package

Comment: I already have python3.8 package. I can see it on git bash but not on this console at the same directory. Maybe have to set the path in console bash separately?